# Run selenium webdriver over adb

Tags: python, selenium, adb

I'm just getting started with the Selenium Python bindings and can successfully perform basic functionality using my computer's browser.  I'd now like to use the Chrome browser on an Android phone which I'm connected to via `adb`.

I've looked online and have seen references to remote web drivers and Selenium grid.  However, I don't know if this is what I need or, if so, what is needed to set this up.

Is there some web driver equivalent of `gdb-server`?

Comment: You can try to establish a TCP port forwarding from the Android device to the host PC.

Comment: But what would Selenium be connecting to?

Comment: A TCP port just as usual

Comment: No, I mean what is on the other end of the socket?  For example, if I were running `gdb` remotely, there would be a `gdb-server` running on the device.